# How to make terminal autocomplete when there are several files/directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

If I have several directories, like:

```
afoo abar
```

sometimes my terminal will refuse autocomplete when I press tab (e.g. "cd a" then tab), and print the list of directories instead. Sometimes it even throws a noisy, annoying sound. Any idea how to make it autocomplete in cases like this? E.g it can show abar first, and then afoo if I press tab again. I saw this is the case in windows, or some applciation in Ubuntu

Answer (score 61):

Something that is a life-saver for me is to have bash cycle through the possibilities instead of showing a dumb list.

As bash is using `readline` for its auto-completion, add the following lines to `~/.inputrc`

*Once you're satisfied and have thoroughly tested below solution for a few days/weeks, **cut and paste** (don't copy!) the same settings from `~/.inputrc` to `/etc/inputrc` which contains the system-wide settings, making this available to all users on your system (including guest).*

#### The codez:

```
# mappings to have up and down arrow searching through history:
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
# mappings to have left and right arrow go left and right: 
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char

# mapping to have [Tab] and [Shift]+[Tab] to cycle through all the possible completions:
"\t": menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

then `exit` your terminal (or remote terminal like putty) and open it again...

#### Examples:

1. When you have 3 files: `file1`, `file2` and `file3` and you type:

   ```
   e fTabTabTab
   ```

   it'll cycle through:

   ```
   e file1
   e file2
   e file3
   ```

   and when you want to cycle backwards, just hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. When you type:

   ```
   very-complicated-command with lots of command line parameters
   ```

   and next time you need the same command, you just type:

   ```
   very↑
   ```

   and it'll type for you:

   ```
   very-complicated-command with lots of command line parameters
   ```

### This will save you a ton of time in bash!  ;-)

Comment: +1,  interesting, but: 1. `~/.inputrc` might be preferable over `/etc/inputrc`, and 2. I think you can set this in `bash` directly: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55203/70524, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16926/70524

Comment: This is quite nice, thanks (and have my upvote). Is there a universal way to show the options it'll loop through, which combines the best of both worlds? I like the tab+tab possibility with folders _and_ subcommands, etc. so I don't have to remember them all (e.g. `git branch <tab through branches>`. However, if I could see a list _and_ tab through its items, that would be great! For directories and files `ls` is an option to see what items are available. However, for subcommands it is not that easy or obvious, unfortunately.

Comment: This works also on PuTTy! Just had to restart it once :)

Comment: @Erik: Apparently, what you asked for [is possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55632/90054) but not going to edit my answer to keep things simple here. (deleted old comment that it is not possible)

Comment: How to put this **TAB** markdown? @Fabby

Comment: @sh.3.ll https://lmgtfy.com/?q=stack+overflow+markdown&s=t

Answer (score 23):

After the 1st <kbd>tab</kbd> you need to insert more letters. So if you type

```
cd a
```

and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> you get nothing and after a second <kbd>tab</kbd> (immediately following) you get a list of the names starting with `a` and then need to insert an `f` to have it auto complete the remainder so

`cd a`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>`f`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

will result in

```
cd afoo
```

Comment: IMHO: This is the right way. I personally find the windows behavior very annoying. Consider the case where you have a lot of files starting with `a` and you need the last one. When you accidentally press tab after `a` you have to cycle through the list of all possible completions to get to the right one.

Comment: @Tobias: when you accidentally hit [Tab] too early [using the other system](https://askubuntu.com/a/607903/344926), there is still [Ctrl][K]...  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

To do it in Bash add the fllowing to your bash file:

```
# make tab cycle through commands after listing
bind '"\t":menu-complete'
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
bind "set completion-ignore-case on"
bind "set menu-complete-display-prefix on"
```

Works nicely. (Taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55203/bash-autocomplete-first-list-files-then-cycle-through-them/527944#527944?newreg=e7f309c967aa45a8ad4252bfd1f8fa30) as mentioned in a comment by @muru).

Answer (score 1):

Fig for linux is in beta: https://fig.io/user-manual/linux

It works very well and has many other features, Ubuntu is one of their supported distros.