# Are there different options for terminal autocomplete (tab) behaviour?

Tags: command-line, auto-completion

I [don't like](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280327/how-to-make-terminal-autocomplete-when-there-are-several-files-directory) my terminal's autocomplete behaviour, to be honest I like windows' cmd behaviour better. Does bash (default shell in ubuntu) come with several options of the autocomplete behaviours? How can I change it?

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179642/how-can-i-make-bash-tab-completion-behave-like-vim-tab-completion It explains how to set up bash to work more like windows, where it cycles through the possible completions.

Comment: I seem to have no ~\.inputrc yet, is this normal? By the way what other options are there besides those in the link? Is there a way to get the list or documentation?

Comment: Create an ~/.inputrc. Gnu's official documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html