# Terminal - Cycle through possible options

Tags: gnome-terminal

In the terminal I use `bind '"\t":menu-complete'` to auto complete my commands using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

If I hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key again, it shows the next choice.

Sometimes I miss the entry and I have to go through the whole list again.

It would be nice if I could cycle backwards using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you doing auto-complete like this? Isn't it simpler to use inbuilt auto-complete and get lists and just add letters as needed? This would also take far less key-presses than having to press TAB a lot.

Comment: @Simplexion how I do it is type a couple of letters then hit tab to fetch the first suggestion. But if there are 5-6 options left and I miss the one I need then I have to press tab a lot. Otherwise its ok

Comment: If you type the first couple of letters and press tab twice it will list all of your options and then you enter the next letter and press tab again. This would be far less key presses than hitting tab to get to the command/entry you are after.

Comment: @Simplexion I know I can always go with what you are suggesting. I still would love to find a way to Shift-Tab though so I could try that too and see if it helps me at all. Do you have any suggestions on how I might do it?

Answer (score 0):

So I saw this post to help with a similar concept that might answer your question, hopefully it works on your OS:

[How to make terminal autocomplete when there are several files/directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280327/how-to-make-terminal-autocomplete-when-there-are-several-files-directory)

Comment: Please, include some details from the post and make your answer presentable... The link could get lost.