# Ubuntu command-line suggestion

Tags: command-line, auto-completion

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to get used to it. but repeating same command in terminal is quit boring. i just want some suggestion to get rid of it and how can i get visible command-line suggestion in terminal.

to clarify..
I'm trying to ask, i want a command-line suggestion when i am writing a command or attempt to write (if i need to install any application suggest please)

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu Desktop with a graphical desktop environment or Ubuntu Server with a text screen interface?

Comment: I recommend checking out the 2 useful answers for this [auto-complete in ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/280327/1193677)

Comment: `history` has a lot of what you did stored :)

Comment: Are you looking for _any_ completion suggestion or _only_ regarding your previously executed commands (see `history`)?

Answer (score 9):

If you use the up arrow on your keyboard, your terminal will write the last line ran. You can use that multiple times to go multiple commands back. If you got too far, use the down arrow to do the opposite. You can also write "!!" and it will replace that with the last command at runtime (after you pressed enter). This trick can also be used inside a command, to add something to the command.

If you press "Tab", your terminal will try to complete the command if its obvious what you want, and if its not obvious, you can press tab again to see the commands you can make from that not-so-obvious command.

Edit, I don't know if this works on Ubuntu server, but it works on desktop

Edit, added info based on comments

Comment: Yes, it works in Ubuntu Server too :-)

Comment: and `history` for a numbered list where you can use !111 to execute line 111 and !! can also be used to add "sudo" when you forgot to add it in the previous command. Those windows users do not know what they are missing ;-)

Comment: And on the theme of using the up-arrow: you can press it as many times as you want to scroll up through the history - useful if you know you typed a command recently but can’t remember exactly how many it was (& if you overshoot you can down-arrow back). There are some tips for navigating on the line if you want to edit a recent command: the ones I find most useful are ctrl-a to go to the start of the line, ctrl-e to the end, meta-f to go forward 1 word and meta-b back 1 word.

Comment: Thank you @Will, I will include that in my answer

Comment: You might add that a double "Tab" gives you a list of suggestions if the auto complete is ambigous.

Comment: Added, thanks André

Answer (score 6):

Another option comes from installing `fzf` (command line fuzzy finder): it's an interactive filter for command-line that can be used with any list, including command history.

You have two alternative ways to install it:

- `sudo apt install fzf`
  or
- `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/.fzf && ~/.fzf/install`

I suggest the second one because it installs also the key-bindings, while the version in the Ubuntu repositories installs `fzf` executable alone.

Key-bindings are important because, once activated, if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and start typing some text, you can search a command in your history.

In the picture below, you can see that typing `apt instal` I got the list of matching commands from my terminal history.

[image: fzf]

For further details, you can visit the [GitHub fzf page](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

Comment: Worth noting ctrl-R is builtin and displays previous history matches and can search forwards and backwards.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can search your bash history to speed up your work. A commonly used one is to add the following lines to your `.inputrc` file in your `~` directory:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Now start typing the first few characters of a command (that your previously used) and press up and down arrow keys to see your commands.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of very simple tricks that are super useful when you have to run very similar commands with just a couple of changes:

- You can use `^string^replacement^` to run the previous command but replacing the first occurrence of `string` with `replacement`. For example:

  ```
  $ echo "Hello there, General Kenobi. What you have there?"
  $ ^there^world^
  echo "Hello world, General Kenobi. What you have there?"
  Hello world, General Kenobi. What you have there?
  ```

  Note that it outputs the command that is actually being run, and then you have the actual output
- You can use `!!:gs/pattern/replacement/` to run the previous command with all occurrences of the regex `pattern` replaced by `replacement`.

  ```
   $ echo "Hello there, General Kenobi. What you have there?"
  Hello there, General Kenobi. What you have there?
  $ !!:gs/there/world/
  echo "Hello world, General Kenobi. What you have world?"
  Hello world, General Kenobi. What you have world?
  ```

  Note that both instances of `there` were changed.
- You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to insert the last argument of the previous command. If you keep pressing the shortcut you cycle with previous commands:

  ```
  $ echo a
  $ echo b
  $ echo c
  $ echo ...
  ```

  On the last line pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> once will insert `c`, pressing it again will swap it out for `b` and again for `a`.

  You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to insert the first argument instead of the last, similarly for the 2nd, 3rd etc:

  ```
  $ echo a b c
  $ echo
  ```

  Here doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> will insert `a`, while using `2` in place of `1` will replace `b` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can “browse” your history of commands executed in the past by using the `reverse-i-search` within the terminal:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Enter a command (or part of it)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> again to cycle through the matches (repeat if required).
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) to **E**xecute the match *or* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) to **C**ancel `reverse-i-search`.

Comment: (Or just press Enter to execute a match)

Comment: 'Enter' seems to also execute the match. 'End' or arrows will let you edit the command before running it. Ctrl+C also aborts the search, and is probably easier to remember.

Comment: Arrow keys also let you edit the command

Answer (score 0):

Use Manter. It is an opensource terminal which has IDE like autocomplete suggestions. https://github.com/iondodon/manter